# How do I just put header and some content under it in Qt Designer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

QtCreator's designer allows you to edit user interface graphically. I was just trying to make some sense of it - what I wanted was a header text centered in the middle and some widget under it, like this:

[image: image description]

But my results look like this, when using vertical layout:

[image: image description]

I placed QLabel on top and QOpenGLWidget on bottom - I only used QOpenGlWidget because it has black background on screenshot. What I really plan on doing is using another QWidget. I used vertical layout then. So how do I get the result on the first image, using QLabel and QWidget?

Comment: Qt Creator has nothing much to do with `.ui` files. It's an IDE, and bundles a plug-in that lets you graphically edit these files, that's all. The `.ui` files are processed by the `uic` tool to generate the `foo_ui.h` files that set up your widget-based UI for you. Where did your idea that `.ui` has anything to do with HTML come from? You do realize the XML is a general data exchange format; modern HTML just happens to be valid XML too.

Comment: I got the idea because it uses stylesheets and because HTML is xml just as the ui files. By the way, HTMH5 sure is not valid XML all the time.

Comment: "I got the idea because it uses stylesheets" The `.ui` file itself doesn't "use" stylesheets. The stylesheet is a string (text) property of individual widgets; it's the widgets that process the stylesheets. The `.ui` file is essentially transparent to stylesheets, they are treated no different than any other text property like widget name, caption, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Qt's use of XML is not a replacement for HTML.

HTML is designed for marking up web pages. Qt's widgets are not web pages!

It appears that you're looking at the box with the text 'content' and thinking of a generic widget. I see that and see a QLabel, which is derived from QWidget after all.

It's probably easier to explain in code how I would go about this, which you can then translate to doing the same in Qt Creator.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Create a root widget (this could also be a QMainWindow, or any other widget)
    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;

    // Layout to arrange the widgets vertically
    QVBoxLayout* pBoxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    pWidget->setLayout(pBoxLayout);

    // The header widget
    QLabel* pHeader = new QLabel("Header");
    pHeader->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    pHeader->setMinimumSize(200, 20);
    pHeader->setMaximumSize(200, 20);
    QFont font = pHeader->font();
    font.setBold(true);
    font.setPixelSize(16);
    pHeader->setFont(font);

    // the content widget
    QLabel* plabel = new QLabel("content");
    plabel->setMinimumSize(200, 200);
    plabel->setMaximumSize(200, 200);
    plabel->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182); border: 5px solid black;");
    plabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    pBoxLayout->addWidget(pHeader);
    pBoxLayout->addWidget(plabel);

    pWidget->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

As you can see here, I've styled the content widget with the use of a Style Sheet. This is really the easiest method, after a bit of practice with them.

The resulting code produces a widget which looks like this: -

[image: Output image]

You can play with dimensions and fonts to match your original image exactly.

Comment: You used native code, not Designer. We're using Designer with CSS stylesheets in our company - maybe I can extrapolate info I need from this answer, but it's not what I hoped for. Also, you you really think you need entire paragraph to talk about how I *"lack experience thinking in Qt's Widgets"*. I mean I just said in my question that I'm new to it, so you don't say...

Comment: I know you were using the Designer. As I state *"It's probably easier to explain in code how I would go about this, which you can then translate to doing the same in Qt Creator."* As for mentioning the lack of experience, I was attempting to give you confidence that Qt can do what you're asking and isn't too difficult once you get used to thinking that way. I'm sorry if that didn't come across the way in which it was intended.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but in the end I ended up with form layout. Box layout isn't even visible in designer for some reason. I will sure return to this answer, but I was asked and I also prefer to create GUI in designer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but note that the "Vertical Layout" in the designer is a  QVBoxLayout. If you right-click on the form (ui file) which has a Vertical Layout in Qt Creator's project , you can select *Open With -> Plain Text Editor* and search for QVBoxLayout, you'll see that's how it is defined.